# Kylin build error on Step 7 Build Base Cuboid

Tags: amazon-emr, kylin

Im trying follow instruction on this [link](http://kylin.apache.org/docs15/tutorial/kylin_sample.html) to create sample cube. Build failed on step 7 with following error message. Any help is appreciated

EMR: 5.4.0
Hbase: 1.3.0
kylin: 2.0.0

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Map input splits are 0 bytes, something is wrong!
at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.common.AbstractHadoopJob.getTotalMapInputMB(AbstractHadoopJob.java:573)
at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.steps.CuboidJob.run(CuboidJob.java:134)
at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.MRUtil.runMRJob(MRUtil.java:102)
at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.common.MapReduceExecutable.doWork(MapReduceExecutable.java:123)
at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:124)
at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.DefaultChainedExecutable.doWork(DefaultChainedExecutable.java:64)
at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:124)
at org.apache.kylin.job.impl.threadpool.DefaultScheduler$JobRunner.run(DefaultScheduler.java:142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

result code:2

Comment: when i checked kylin logs i see there are no input files to read for this step hence failing, not sure why input files are missing for step 7  mapred.FileInputFormat:221 : Total input paths to process : 0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe date column null or records not in between start and end date.

Open kylin.log in logs folder and check query which is storing intermediate data
Execute that query in hive check result is coming or not 
(query like this)

```
""""INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE kylin_intermediate_cube2_70c3e71d_f9a8_4ed1_91a9_d12dd649a9b1 SELECT                                                          
BMS_TRANSACTIONS1.MAX_SEQ                                                                                                                            
,BMS_TRANSACTIONS1.TRX_TYPE                                                                                                                          
FROM BMS.BMS_TRANSACTIONS1 as BMS_TRANSACTIONS1                                                                                                      
WHERE (BMS_TRANSACTIONS1.TRX_DATE >= '2012-04-09' AND BMS_TRANSACTIONS1.TRX_DATE < '2017-07-27')                                                     
;     """
```